# which rule can be used to compute the probability of $P \{ a<X\leq b \}$?

Tags: probability

assume 
$
Z \sim N(1.4, 4)
$

then
$\dfrac{Z-1.4}{2} \sim N(0, 1)$

which rule can conduct left side of equal sign to right side?

$$
P \{ 1 < X \leq 1.6 \}
= P \{ \frac{1-1.4}{2} < 
\frac{X-1.4}{2} \leq 
\frac{1.6-1.4}{2} \}
$$

it seems that there is a rule to compute the probability of $P \{ a<X\leq b \}$, what is the name?

I have already known

$$
P \{ a<X\leq b \}
= P(\{X \leq b\} - \{X \leq a \})
$$

I want to know the detail of this procedure of

from
$P(a<X)$
to
$
P ( \dfrac{1-1.4}{2} < 
\dfrac{X-1.4}{2})
$
 or something else like it.

Comment: Do you want to compute?

Answer (score 1):

The event $\{a\lt X\leq b\}$ is also the event $\left\{\tfrac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\lt \tfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq\tfrac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right\}$ since you are simply applying a *linear transformation*.

So since they are the same event, then they have the same probability measure; because the measure is a *function*.