# how to justify the probability of a linear transformation of a event?

Tags: probability

I am confused when I trying to understand this [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157798/656367)

I have already known

the probability of a linear function $Y = g(X) = aX + b$, where X is a random variable with a PMF P_X(x)

is

$$
P_Y(y) = 
\sum\limits_{x|y=g(x)} P_X(x)
$$

how to justify the probability equation of a event like this?

$$
P(
    \{
        X > a
    \}
) = 
P( 
    \{
    \dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma} >
    \dfrac{a-\mu}{\sigma})
    \}
)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of simple algebra (for $\sigma > 0$): $$\begin{align}
x>a &\iff x-\mu > a-\mu \\
 &\iff \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}.
\end{align}$$
So $\{X> a\}$ occurs if and only if $\left\{\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right\}$ occurs. Thus the two probabilities are the same.

Comment: thanks, I helps. and would you please give a real life example to illustrate this transformation? i am having some difficulties to get a complete understanding of it.

Comment: Maybe just consider some numbers. Imagine for now that $\mu=0$. So you need to understand $x>a\iff x/\sigma > a/\sigma$. Could you see why this would be true if $\sigma =2$ for instance (so $x>a \iff x/2 > a/2$)?

Comment: What is so difficult?  All outcomes where $X>a$ are outcomes where $(X-\mu)/\sigma>(a-\mu)/\sigma$ because of the algebra: $x>a\iff (x-b)/c>(a-b)/c$ (when $c>0$) $$\{\omega:X(\omega)>a\}=\{\omega:(X(\omega)-\mu)/\sigma=(a-\mu)/\sigma\}$$